# Using Phpstorm with Xampp-- stopped loading pages

Tags: php, xampp, localhost, phpstorm

I've been using these PHPstorm and Xampp without any issues until a couple weeks ago. It simply stopped running my webpages while I was working one day. I hadn't even made changes to a webpage or the settings-- It worked one second, and not the next.

I've made some progress, the pages will run the first time I run PHPstorm (Or Netbeans), but my browser will not be able to resolve localhost after that.

I'm banging my head against the desk, I don't know what to do here.

I have xampp using the default port 80, and I've checked a hundred times for anything else using 80. I don't see anything that should interrupt my connection...

Comment: smells like you may be doing some sort of HTTP redirect,  perhapd using a command-line client like `wget` could be useful

Comment: I have had similar issue, I ended up reinstalling XAMP and it works, what was the reason, no body knows, remember to take backup of your configuration files. let me know, if this helps or not.

Comment: Maytham, Ive reinstalled two times now. That's how I made what little progress I have seen. But it only displays one time, and then u can no longer view my projects until I restart.